# Getting all available time slot ranges from bookings table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a a range of time-slots available to in my booking system taking into consideration any existing bookings and their finish times. 
Time slots are in 15 minute intervals and bookings can only be taken between 09:00 and 18:00.

The problem I'm getting is that it doesn't show *all* available time slots. In [this SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fc84/1) with the schema and data below it misses out the last time slot range, this isnt however restricted to just the last record.. If I had only two bookings ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c6386/1)), it still only shows one booking.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE bookings
    (`id` int, `time_from` datetime, `time_to` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO bookings
    (`id`, `time_from`, `time_to`)
VALUES
    (2, '2013-11-20 09:00:00', '2013-11-20 09:15:00'),
    (3, '2013-11-20 11:00:00', '2013-11-20 11:30:00'),
    (4, '2013-11-20 12:00:00', '2013-11-20 12:45:00'),
    (5, '2013-11-20 16:30:00', '2013-11-20 16:45:00'),
    (6, '2013-11-20 16:45:00', '2013-11-20 17:15:00')
;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT available_from, available_to
FROM (
    SELECT @lasttime_to AS available_from, time_from AS available_to, @lasttime_to := time_to
    FROM (SELECT time_from, time_to
          FROM bookings
          WHERE time_to >= '2013-11-20 09:00'
            AND time_from < '2013-11-20 18:00'
      ORDER BY time_from) e
    JOIN (SELECT @lasttime_to := NULL) init) x
WHERE available_to > DATE_ADD(available_from, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

**Result:**

```
|      AVAILABLE_FROM |                    AVAILABLE_TO |
|---------------------|---------------------------------|
| 2013-11-20 09:15:00 | November, 20 2013 11:00:00+0000 |
| 2013-11-20 11:30:00 | November, 20 2013 12:00:00+0000 |
| 2013-11-20 12:45:00 | November, 20 2013 16:30:00+0000 |
```

There should have been another row here from `2013-11-20 17:15` to `2013-11-20 17:45`

Comment: It works for me as expected if you add another booking that starts at your maximum time slot.

Comment: @wils484 Yes it does work, but does not show all available slots, if you refer to the first SQL fiddle, it is missing the 17:15 to 17:45 timeslot.

Comment: Does my answer make sense? I guess if you are looking for times that can be assigned as booking start times, the `UNION ALL` value would be `2013-11-20 17:45`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're selecting from bookings to get your open timeslot beginning and end times. The problem is that the endpoint of all time slots isn't in your database (if I'm understanding correctly, the last slot should be `2013-11-20 17:15` to `2013-11-20 18:00`, right?).

Kind of ugly, but adding the endpoint as an appointment seems to work.

```
SELECT Available_from, Available_to
FROM (
SELECT @lasttime_to AS Available_from, time_from AS Available_to, @lasttime_to := time_to
FROM (SELECT time_from, time_to
      FROM bookings
      WHERE time_to >= '2013-11-20 08:59'
        AND time_from < '2013-11-20 22:01'
       UNION ALL
     SELECT '2014-11-20 18:00', '2014-11-20 18:00'
           ORDER BY time_from 

     ) e
JOIN (SELECT @lasttime_to := NULL) init) x
WHERE Available_to > DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: this only fixes the issue when using the exact dataset in my first fiddle, this doesn't fix the query. check the second fiddle to see other inconsistencies.

Comment: Is there a way to improve that kind of query ? I'm using this query to find "available time slots". It works very great but it's a little slow (using it into a while loop to find all available time slots)